# Trouble accessing youtube API via VPN

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, vpn, youtube.net-api

Youtube is not accessible in my region, I use a VPN (cyberghost VPN) and use it to hit youtube APIs, to be specific this is how im requesting (through .NET client library):

below is my sample code

```
YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings(Config.YoutubeApplicationName, Config.YouTubeDeveloperKey, Config.YouTubeConnectionUserName, Config.YouTubeConnectionPassword);
YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);

Video newVideo = new Video();

newVideo.Title = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("XXXXXXXXXXX", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
newVideo.Keywords = "xxxxx";
newVideo.Description = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = true;

FormUploadToken token = request.CreateFormUploadToken(newVideo);
```

i get an email about "suspicious login attempt" which makes sense...since Im now logging in through a different country, but I thought I would be able to whitelist some IPs and get through...CANT find any such option there!!

#### question 1:

Is there an option in youtube developer account to whitelist an IP (a set of IPs)?

#### Question 2:

If its not possible, HOW else do I do it ? (one possible solution seems to be generation of "Application specific password" )?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend switching to OAuth 2 instead of ClientLogin. Using OAuth 2, you authenticate once in a browser using your Google Account, authorize access, and then you get back a token that can be reused to make API calls without having to login again.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2